# Can you pass an iQueryable container to the Viewbag in ASP.Net MVC and query it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

There is very little info about this online but I was wondering if it's possible to pass an iQueryable<> to the Viewbag and in the view perform a query on it.

I am trying to do it but intellisense says it can't resolve the symbol. I would rather not create a View Model just to pass in this list because the underlying code is already in place.

My view looks like:

```
 <%: ViewBag.ParentGroups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.MaterialGroup.ParentId) %>
```

It says that x.Id can't be resolved but each Object in Parent Groups definitely has an Id. Is the problem that the ViewBag on the view-side can't strongly type the objects it contains?

Edit - I think I solved the problem by copying the viewbag into a strongly typed variable.

```
<% IQueryable<MaterialGroup> topGroups = ViewBag.ParentGroups; %>
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use an IQueryable from a view. You should prepare the data for the view in the controller action.

Comment: How else could I do it then? Would I have to pass the data as a List and then execute a foreach loop and do my comparisons there? What I am trying to do is display one of the topGroups for each table cell depending on if the cell data's id matches the id of the top group.

Comment: You should do the comparisons in the controller action and create a view model and pass that to the view which has the single and only responsibility: display the data. display does not include calculations.